# How to maximize command prompt in windows xp

Tags: windows, command-prompt, maximize-window

I am on windows xp,

**Is there any way to maximize my cmd.exe window?**

I am doing some mysql and it is so difficult to read results of my queries in such a small window.

Why maximize does not really maximizes it?
Is there a way for maximizing?
Or maybe an alternative command prompt I can use?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommand that you use powershell

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/powershell/download.mspx

It also support full screen mode, and some other nice feature.

Comment: Powershell is a command interpreter, not a terminal application. You still have to run it from under cmd.exe or a similar app. It does *not* actually solve the problem.

Comment: This does not answer the question, regardless of the fact it was an accepted answer. Suggesting alternate tools is not what the original question asked for.

Answer (score 14):

Click on the top left icon in the window (the `"C:\"` one) and select "Properties".

Then select the "Layout" tab and change the window size to what you want it to be (I have 128x50 for the screen and 128x999 for the scroll buffer). You can also optionally set the top left position (I always have it at 1,1) if you don't want Windows itself deciding where the window goes.

When you click on OK, make sure you tell it to modify the shortcut that started the window.

Then it will remember.

This is for XP, other MS operating systems may vary slightly but the general idea should be the same.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

1. In the Command window, right click the Title
   bar and select Properties from the
   popup menu.  The property sheet
   appears.
2. In the property sheet, select 'Full
       Screen' in the 'Display Options'
       box.
3. Close the property sheet by clicking
       OK and select 'Save proeprties for
       future windows with same title'.

Answer (score 2):

### Command Window Default Properties

Click on the sytem menu, or with focus set on the Command Windows, press Alt+Space, and select Properties. Change your Font, Window Size, and so on. I always change my Window Size (on the Layout tab) to Width 80 by Height 65 and Screen Buffer Size to 80 by 300.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/), it seems to be about the most promising *window* enhancement for cmd.exe.

I have to say, cmd.exe is probably the worst part of windows! Especially the copy pasting support, etc.

Personally, I use putty to ssh into a Linux box when I really need to do command line work, you can't go past Bash.

Even though you could install that on windows using [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), which will allow you to use another console, although this doesn't have the ability to override the windows cmd.exe, it might be worth a shot given that you are trying to use a command line application, and not windows :).

Comment: You can fix the copy/paste quite easily so that the mouse works. Under the properties, options tab, just select quick edit. Then you use the mouse-left-drag to select, mouse-right to copy (if you have a selection) and mouse-right to paste (if there's no selection) - invaluable. And the cmd language has come a long way since the bad old DOS days, although not many people seem to realize it. It's still not a wart on the derriere of bash but it's better than it was.

Answer (score 0):

Access **Properties** by right clicking on top of the CMD window, go back to the Font tab, select either 10 x 18 or 12 x 16, and then click OK. You'll then need to go back to the Layout tab and reset the Screen Buffer Size Width to the appropriate value. For example, I selected the 10 x 18 font size and then changed the Screen Buffer Size Width to 160X300 and window size width to 134X37.